# Two problems using siunitx

Tags: luatex, fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math, lucida

I have two problems with the `siunitx` package. After reading the documentation and searching the internet without success, I hope someone can help me:

```
\documentclass[12pt, 
        ]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{ 
        mode = math, 
        detect-all, 
        exponent-product = \cdot, 
        number-unit-separator=\text{\,}, 
        output-decimal-marker={\text{,}}, 
}     

\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\usechemmodule{all} 
\chemsetup{greek = {fontspec}} 

\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT} 
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math} 

\begin{document} 

\SI{5}{\ohm} $\Omega$ 

\end{document}
```

**Problem #1:**

In the `\sisetup` part, I set the mode explicitly to `math`. Doing so, I would expect the both omegas, the Ohm and the math-mode-Omega, to look identical, i.e., using the same font (Libertinus Math in this case). Why isn't that the case?

**Problem #2:**

If I compile the given MWE with LuaLaTeX, the SI-Omega (`\ohm`) is not displayed. If I do one of the following three things, the `\ohm` is displayed (this means that the sign itself is available):

- comment out the `detect-all` line inside the `\sisetup`;
- change to another main font (what I definitely don't want to do);
- comment out the three lines related to the chemmacros packet.

It seems strange to me, that other fonts don't have problems with either `detect-all` nor the `chemmacros` lines.

What could be the reason for this to issues or am I doing something basically wrong?

PS: I am using the Lucida Version from TUG as well as the latest version of TeXLive 2017 (all packages are up to date).

=====================**UPDATE**=====================

Yesterday here was an answer, which suggested reordering the commands. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. Anyway, I tried something else: Switching to the Type-1 form of the Lucida font leads to the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               ]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for pdfLaTeX
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
        mode = math,
        detect-all,
        exponent-product = \cdot,
        number-unit-separator=\text{\,},
        output-decimal-marker={\text{,}},
}     

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\usepackage{lucimatx}

\begin{document}
\SI{5}{\ohm} $\Omega$

\end{document}
```

If I compile this new code with `LuaLaTeX` and without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I get an Omega but in the `LaTeX` standard font (CMR). Compiling the code with `pdfLaTeX` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, I get the \ohm-Omega in the right font (Lucida). So, maybe the problem is rather an encoding issue than a package issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why Libertinus Math instead of Lucida Bright Math? Anyway, the issue seems to be with chemmacros

Comment: You may want to consider asking only one question per question. That makes your question easier to answer and more useful for others. Following our discussion in https://golatex.de/zwei-probleme-mit-siunitx-t20542.html there is https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/334 for the first issue.

Comment: When I try to complile you MWE with LuaLaTeX, it does not seem to find the Lucida Bright OT  font. If I change it to times for instance, everything appears on the pdf document. Could you have a look at the log when running `lualatex doc.tex` in a terminal ?

Comment: @egreg The different fonts are for showing you issue #1. How can you say that this is related to chemmacros, since deleting detect-all also works? @ BambOo the log rises no errors or warnings. The Lucida font is a commercial one, you have to buy it. But as I wrote in the starting post, other fonts seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround, at least I would consider this as a workaround since the `\micro` symbol works without any changes.

By adding

```
    math-ohm = \ensuremath{\upOmega},
    text-ohm = Ω,
```

to the `\sisetup` it works as expected. Nevertheless, I would appreciate a more fundamental answer to the generell problem (especially why does the `\micro` symbol work?). Interestingly, I've tried this version (since it is recommended in the `\siunitx`manual (for `XeTeX`)) before making the initial post and it had not worked... Maybe some typing error. Since I use Lucida as text font as well as for math, any difference should be irrelevant in my special case.